# Database architecture: When records having different number of attributes (columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have these records

```
    ID 1: has attributes A,B,D
    ID 2: has attributes B,C
    ID 3: has attributes F
    ID 4: has attributes C,G
    .....(Attributes will not duplicate in the same record)
```

Total estimated number of records: ~180,000

Total number of attributes: 70, increasing

Example of queries I'm going to do:

1. `SELECT * from table WHERE (has attribute B)`
2. `SELECT * from table WHERE (has attributes B & D)`
3. `SELECT * from table WHERE (has 2 attributes)`
4. `SELECT * from table WHERE (has >=3 attributes)`
5. `SELECT count(*) from table WHERE (has attribute B)`

What is the best database architecture?

---

**Design 1: Storing attributes as 1s & 0s**

```
ID|A|B|C|D|E|F|...
 1|1|1|0|1|0|0|...
 2|0|1|1|0|0|0|...
 3|0|0|0|0|0|1|...
```

Problems:

1. New columns needed to be added periodically when new attribute appears
2. Much redundant data (0s), as more than 80% of data has only 1 attribute, and less than 0.01% of records will have more than 8 attributes.

---

**Design 2: Store attributes as a CSV string**

```
ID|Attributes
 1|A,B,D,
 2|B,C,
 3|F,
```

Problems:

1. Slow query when I do

```
SELECT * from table WHERE attributes LIKE '%B,%' AND attributes LIKE '%D,%'
```

---

**Design 3: Each attribute has its own table storing record IDs**

```
Table Attribute A
ID
 1
 4
 5
...

Table Attribute B
ID
 1
 7
10
...

Table Attribute C
ID
 2
 8
 9
...
```

Problems

1. Many tables
2. New tables needed to be added periodically
3. How to do `SELECT * from table WHERE id (appears in exactly 3 tables)`?

These are the designs I can think of, please propose any good architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, *none* of your designs are optimal (the third is the best), and I recommend a single junction table which relates ID valued to their attributes, e.g.

```
ID | attr
1  | A
1  | B
1  | D
2  | B
2  | C
3  | F
4  | C
4  | G
```

This is the most normalized approach.  To see why this design is optimal, see how easy it is to find all IDs which have attribute B:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE attr = 'B';
```

It is also fairly straightforward to find all IDs having both attributes B and D:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE attr IN ('B', 'D')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(attr) <> MAX(attr);
```

Your first two suggestions would make it much harder to write these queries (give it a try), and in general it is bad practice to store CSV in database tables.  Your third suggestion does store the relationships correctly, but it unnecessarily spreads out data across multiple tables.

A more general form of the above query which can easily be extended to any number of IDs is:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE attr IN ('B', 'D')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr) = 2;
```

Comment: How about if finding IDs having attributes B and D and E (or more)?